# icon on my navigation dropdown disappears

Tags: html, css

this is the link for the navigation that i am having a problem

http://www.3dghosting.com/mucci-navigation/

the icon on the second drop down menu will disappear when i mouse-over on the second drop down

can anyone help me with this?

this is the code

```
#navigation-main li:hover ul li.tomatoes a:hover{   


    background:#737475 url(images/navs/tomatoes.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    color:#fff;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the background image being set on :hover. Therefore when the mouse is moved to the second menu, the image disappears. Instead style the container, but have it hidden by default and then when hovering, have it displayed

Comment: can you give me a sample code for that pastor? thanks for your help